# How to install east asian languages fonts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, chinese

Back in Windows XP we had an option to install those fonts. How to do so in the newest version of Windows?

Chinese characters aren't rendered in my notepad nor in setup applications.

Answer (score 2):

Try out Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative Tab -> Change System Locale and then set the region and language there. If this doesn't work, try changing the default keyboard. Other than that, Win7 seems to have been easier to set up with Japanese (my East Asian language) than WinXP was.

Comment: It would work if I had the `Ultimate` version. Oh, wait, I have it.

Comment: As I don't know chinese very well I'm not sure I'll be able to revert it though

Comment: It doesn't change the operating system language, just the ability to display it. The language of the OS itself isn't easy to change... you would need the version of Windows for that language to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise, you can change your system locale to the language you are missing, then change it back to English. The missing language will stay installed even after you change back to English.

Comment: This si false, the language will NOT stay installed.